# Efficiency regarding storing HashMap values vs. referencing values

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

Morning all! I was coding today using a hash map and was wondering about the comparison of efficiency in a certain case that I hope hasn't been answered. Lets say I have a file of data where each line is an entry, and three columns with the following fields: number of blocks, starting block, ending block. I use hash map where the keys are the three column data fields. I essentially can find out the number of blocks for each entry by taking the ending block of that entry, subtracting the starting entry, and adding one. For example:

Num of Blocks| Starting Block | Ending block

```
    2           1          2
```

Which is more efficient: to simply omit the num of blocks field from the hash map, and calculating it by map.get("ending block") - map.get("starting block") + 1 (which in this case is 2-1+1), or to simply store num of blocks in the map X number of entries and calling it by map.get("num of blocks");

Sorry if this is a dumb question as I am only a little bit experienced in using hash maps.

Comment: I am not sure but if I were you I would do performance testing by finding computation time using System.nanoTime() and memory usage using the java garbage collector. This doesn't answer your question though, sorry!

Comment: @Aayush Actually that's a very good idea. I would do that now but im unfortunately at work. If I don't get an answered, I will most definitely try with varied amounts of entries. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: why are you using a map? why not two variables to hold the start and end blocks??

Comment: @Bohemian Realistically, I would be dealing with very large amounts of data with more than the three columns mentioned, and I have to reorganize the data for output so assigning values to key's seems to be the most efficient way of handling said data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on your data and purpose of your hash map.
If the data is large and then you do away with storing the number of blocks. But if you can afford that, then I would say to probably keep it as you would need to enter it only once, and then you can get it any number of times. So essentially you are calling only one get on the map. Whereas if you dont store it, you to get two values from the hashmap.
Another scenario is that if you need to get the starting and ending block each time regardless of the use case, then you can omit number of blocks as you will have  to make those get calls anyway.

I hope I answered your query.

Comment: Actually, that is a good point. I do have to use starting and ending blocks. But I was more so curious whether or not a store and call is more efficient than two calls.

Comment: As I said, store and call is more efficient as you would store once and read many times. Its better to read one value instead of two every time.